# Speed up R's grep during an if conditional %in% operation

Tags: r

I'm in need of some R for-loop and grep optimisation assistance.

I have a data.frame made up of columns of different data types. 42 of these columns have the name "treatmentmedication_code_#", where # is a number 1 to 42.

There is a lot of code so a reproducible example is quite tricky. As a compromise, the following code is the precise operation I need to optimise.

```
for(i in 1:nTreatments) {
      ...lots of code...
  controlsDrugStatusDF <- cbind(controlsTreatmentDF, Drug=0)
  
  for(n in 1:nControls) {
    if(treatment %in% controlsDrugStatusDF[n,grep(pattern="^treatmentmedication_code*",x=colnames(controlsDrugStatusDF))]) {
      controlsDrugStatusDF$Drug[n] <- 1
    } else {
      controlsDrugStatusDF$Drug[n] <- 0
    }
  }
}
```

`treatment` is some coded medication e.g., 145374524. The condition inside the `if` statement is very slow. It checks to see whether the treatment value is present in any one of those columns defined by the grep for the row `n`. To make matters worse, this is done for every treatment, thus the `i` for-loop.

Short of launching multiple processes or massacring my data.frames into lots of separate matrices then pasting them together and converting them back into a data.frame, are there any notable improvements one could make on the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of optimization, the `grep` for selecting the columns can be done outside the loop.  Regarding the `treatments` part it is not clear.  Consider that it is a vector of values.  We can use

```
nm1 <- grep("^treatmentmedication_code*", 
            colnames(controlsDrugStatusDF), values = TRUE)
nm2 <- paste0("Drug", seq_along(nm1))
controlsDrugStatusDF[nm2] <- lapply(controlsDrugStatusDF[nm1], 
          function(x)
            +(x %in% treatments))
```

Comment: Thanks! Putting those greps outside of the for-loop will definitely help. I'm just chewing over the lapply functionality. From too many years of C programming!

Comment: @AnthonyNash I couldn't parse `lots of code` in the loop.  So, what I did is get the column names that have the 'treatmentmedication_code' ('nm1').  Then, do a single loop (it can be `for` loop or `lapply` on the subset of columns (here 'treatments' I assume as a vector of values)., then convert the values into a logical (`%in%`- if the column contains any of treatments, it will be TRUE or else FALSE.  The `+` will coerce the logical to biinary (TRUE -> 1, FALSE -> 0) and assign this to new columns 'Drug1', 'Drug2', ..

Comment: Thank you so much! You've helped a lot. I pulled apart the documentation on lapply (it had been a while since I last used it) and now what was taking 3 days to run, is going to take about an hour, tops! Thanks again.